# inserting custom li class to wp_list_pages

Tags: theme-development, child-pages, wp-list-pages

I currently have a parent page with some child pages. I am able to list these child pages but would like to insert a custom li class. The `wp_list_pages` outputs `<li class="page-item number"></li>`. I would like for it to output `<li class="hvr-underline"></li>`. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );

if ( $children) : ?>
    <ul class="menu ">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Just to check. Any reason you can't put a class on the ul and address the elements as ul.my_class li instead?

Comment: I have a global animation class that i would like to place where the li is, that way the animation is only called once in the css

Comment: And you can't use a more complex selector to do that?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook I just used your method of having the animation specific to the li

Comment: I've turned the comments into an answer.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) allows you to include a walker function. That would give you complete freedom to add any classes you want, but it's no a beginner's method. You could start by [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329494/how-to-add-class-on-wp-list-pages-children).

If you want a simple search and replace on the class, as your question seems to indicate, you can use the [`wp_list_pages` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_pages/) like this:

```
add_filter ('wp_list_pages','wpse241119_replace_class',10,3);
function wpse241119_replace_class ($output, $r, $pages) {
  $output = str_replace ('page-item number', 'hvr-underline', $output);
  return $output;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's no reason to stop you, you could solve this simply by adding a class to the ul and using a more complex selector in your CSS or JavaScript:

```
$children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );

if ( $children) : ?>
    <ul class="menu wpse241119_list">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;
```

And then address each `li` as `ul.wpse241119_list li` or if the list might be nested, `ul.wpse241119_list > li` to catch the top level list items.